# How do I center my image between my topnav and footer?

Tags: html, css

This is my first attempt in developing a website. I tried different solutions but nothing worked! Basically, I have a topnav and a footer in my webpage and I want to center a image in between them. Can anyone help please?

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer {
  padding: 2px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#"> About Me </a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<figure>
  <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="image" style="width: 50%;">
</figure>

<footer>
  <p>
    <em>This website... &copy; 2020</em>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
      figure
     {
     Height:100%;
     Background-position:center;
      Width:100%;
     }
```

Comment: Hey sorry I misunderstood your solution earlier. It worked fine!!! Thanks a lot!!!